# How to integrate any of the file sharing services with a website

Tags: dropbox, google-drive-api

I'm looking for a service like Dropbox or Google Drive that will actually allow to display the content of the folder on a website. I don't want to display just a link, I would like the whole hierarchy to be displayed. Is there anything like that available?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at qnext.  It works as a facebook app.  Still in beta by maybe it will help.